# llvm array of 5 ints is compiled into 16 bytes array global var

Tags: arrays, assembly, static, llvm, llvm-ir

I am trying to create a 5 ints array and initialize it. My understanding is that it should show up as a 4*5 = 20 bytes but it always gets compiled as a 16 bytes array and the initialization ends up overwriting another array.

Objdump is showing that the size of the global objects into the object file is 16 bytes, and i have no idea what is happening.

The bc file produced by a executable that is using llvm8.0.1 as library, the object is produced by clang-8.0.1, the ll is produced by llvm-dis8.0.1

the idea of the code is to set intVectorConstant to 0, -1, -2, -3, -4
and intVector to 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

I am sorry i couldn't take away lines from the ll and compile those to make it simpler but if i run llvm-as it's failing and i am not sure why.

```
; ModuleID = 'lowerer/test/arraySimulation.bc'
source_filename = "Int Test Simulation"

@intVectorConstant = global [5 x i32] 0
@intVectorConstant_old = global [5 x i32] 0
@intVectorConstant_str = global [18 x i8] c"intVectorConstant\00"
@intVector = global [5 x i32] 0
@intVector_old = global [5 x i32] 0
@intVector_str = global [10 x i8] c"intVector\00"

define internal void @init() {
entry:
  %0 = alloca [5 x i32]
  %1 = getelementptr [5 x i32], [5 x i32]* %0, i32 0, i32 0
  store i32 -1, i32* %1
  %2 = getelementptr [5 x i32], [5 x i32]* %0, i32 0, i32 1
  store i32 -2, i32* %2
  %3 = getelementptr [5 x i32], [5 x i32]* %0, i32 0, i32 2
  store i32 -3, i32* %3
  %4 = getelementptr [5 x i32], [5 x i32]* %0, i32 0, i32 3
  store i32 -4, i32* %4
  %5 = getelementptr [5 x i32], [5 x i32]* %0, i32 0, i32 4
  store i32 -5, i32* %5
  %6 = load [5 x i32], [5 x i32]* %0
  store [5 x i32] %6, [5 x i32]* @intVectorConstant
  store [5 x i32] %6, [5 x i32]* @intVectorConstant_old
  %7 = alloca [5 x i32]
  %8 = getelementptr [5 x i32], [5 x i32]* %7, i32 0, i32 0
  store i32 1, i32* %8
  %9 = getelementptr [5 x i32], [5 x i32]* %7, i32 0, i32 1
  store i32 2, i32* %9
  %10 = getelementptr [5 x i32], [5 x i32]* %7, i32 0, i32 2
  store i32 3, i32* %10
  %11 = getelementptr [5 x i32], [5 x i32]* %7, i32 0, i32 3
  store i32 4, i32* %11
  %12 = getelementptr [5 x i32], [5 x i32]* %7, i32 0, i32 4
  store i32 5, i32* %12
  %13 = load [5 x i32], [5 x i32]* %7
  store [5 x i32] %13, [5 x i32]* @intVector
  store [5 x i32] %13, [5 x i32]* @intVector_old
  ret void
}
```

If i run

```
clang -c file.bc -o out
objdump out -t | grep intVector
```

I get

```
0000000000000020 g     O .bss   0000000000000014 intVector
0000000000000000 g     O .bss   0000000000000014 intVectorConstant
0000000000000010 g     O .bss   0000000000000014 intVectorConstant_old
0000000000000000 g     O .data  0000000000000012 intVectorConstant_str
0000000000000030 g     O .bss   0000000000000014 intVector_old
0000000000000012 g     O .data  000000000000000a intVector_str
```

Comment: Can't reproduce on my machine. In my case, variables differ by `0x20`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, i was using ConstantAggrerateZero::get(int32Type) as initializer of the globals instead of ConstantAggregateZero::get(int32ArrayType) and that was producing

```
@intVector_old = global [5 x i32] 0
```

with the right initializer it becomes:

```
@intVectorConstant = global [5 x i32] zeroinitializer
```

and now they do have a offset of 32 bytes in the object file.